# Is there some Apache config that can filter out double-slash from URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have web software where I need to have URLs like this

> http://site.com/page/var1/val1/var2//var3/val3

Then I catch such URLs in .htaccess, redirect to a php file which then parses that to $_GET and forwards everything to main app. That double-slash is important, it means that var2 has been set and contains an empty value, in other words $var2!==NULL.

On some servers it works as expected but on some servers it doesn't, the URL is silently converted to

> http://site.com/page/var1/val1/var2/var3/val3

which of course breaks everything because it parses it to $var1='val1', $var2='var3', $val3=''.

Unfortunately I already don't have access to one of those servers and I don't remember 100% whether it was Apache or not but let's assume it was Apache since that's the server we deal with most of the time.

Is there may be some config that controls that? That turns on/off the cleaning of double-slashes.

Comment: Maybe you should come up with a URL scheme that doesn't rely on malformed URIs to operate.

Comment: The double-slashes count as an invalid URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache strips such empty path segments before mapping it onto the file system. To get the original requested URI in mod_rewrite, check the request line in `%{THE_REQUEST}`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (/[^?\ ]*)
RewriteRule …
```

You can then reference the match of `RewriteCond` with `%1`.